# Validation rule getting quarterly months

Tags: validation, validation-rule, date

I am trying to get only the months March,June,September,December.  Not sure why this isn't working, I use Ceiling which gives the rounded estimate.

```
OR( 
CloseDate = DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), CEILING(MONTH(TODAY())/3) ,15), 
CloseDate = DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),CEILING(MONTH(TODAY())/3),16)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That logic does not make sense. May, e.g., is 5, so `CEILING(MONTH(TODAY()) / 3)` on May 1 yields `CEILING(5/3)`, which is 2. So then your rule goes off in February.

What you actually want is probably the [`MOD()`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5) function. You're interested in the months 3, 6, 9, and 12, i.e, months evenly divisible by 3. Hence `MOD(MONTH(CloseDate), 3) = 0`.

I don't think you're going to be able to shoehorn that into your `OR()` formula, so you'll need to rearrange the logic somewhat. I'm not sure where you're going with these formulas, though, so this may be an x-y problem.

Comment: what do you mean x,y problem?

Comment: I want to identify the last 2 weeks of the last quarter month.

Comment: Leading with that statement of your underlying goal can help produce better answers that take you further along!